# How to obtain instances of all subclasses of sealed class?

Tags: java, java-sealed-type

Is there a way to get a collection of instances of subclasses, which are permitted in `sealed` class?

It would be nice to have something similar to `Enum.values()` method, because I don't want to collect them manually.

The best I could do is:

```
abstract sealed class Color permits Green, Red /*, ...*/ {

  Iterable<Color> values() {
    return Arrays.stream((Class<Color>[]) Color.class.getPermittedSubclasses())
        .flatMap(subclass -> {
          try {
            return Stream.of(subclass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance());
          } catch (ReflectiveOperationException ignore) {
            return Stream.empty();
          }
        }).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: In what way do you want a "better" solution? Yours looks pretty good to me.

Comment: I think other than annotation processing + code generation you're out of options

Comment: @Sweeper I hope to find more elegant solution

Comment: I believe you want to implement a factory method. The idea behind sealed classes was to limit inheritance not to provide a factory method like the one you mentioned with the enums.

For example, Spring and other frameworks provide this kind of functionality with interfaces, collecting their implementations, but those are not built java functionalities. I don't think that another non-hacky reflection-based solution exists. If there's another I am interested in it.

Comment: You could also just create an array directly in the method or for a class variable. I mean, the classes are fixed at compile time, so what's the point in using a dynamic solution? You could argue, you would need to change multiple places when changing the permitted types, but I think, `sealed` is not intended for such extendable hierarchies. I mean, the point in using `sealed` *is* to reduce the extendability. I think `sealed class Color permits Green, Red` is strange, because there *are* other colors.